# Probability of swapping elements in an array

Tags: probability

Given an array with n numbers (n>30). Perform the following steps:

- Compare the first element with the second element. If the first one is greater than the second one, swap their positions in the array.
- Compare the second element with the third element. If the second one is greater than the third one, swap their positions in the array.

.....

Keep doing the above steps until the last element of the array is compared.

What is the probability of the case that the value of the 10th element being moved to the 30th element.

---

My attempt is: In order for this case to happen, the 10th element must be the largest number of the first 10 elements AND the 10th element must also be the largest number of the next 21 elements (from 10th to 30th). However, I don't know how to present it into probability.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are probably meant to assume the numbers are all different and are distributed randomly in the array with all permutations equally likely.

Comment: Yes. Many thanks for your answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are $30$ numbers in the first $30$, so the probability the $n$th of the $30$ is the largest is $\frac{1}{30}$.

So the probability the $10$th is the largest of the first $30$ is $\frac{1}{30}$.

But if you want the $10$th not to move further than position $30$, then it must be smaller then the $31$st.  The  probability that $31$st is the largest and the $10$th is the second largest of the first $31$ numbers in the array is $\frac{1}{31} \times \frac{1}{30}=\frac{1}{930}$.